# cp: cannot stat error: No such file or directory

Tags: build, sdk, cuda, makefile

I was trying to build the Rodinia benchmark suite on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server.
I had already installed the **cuda 4.0** in the /usr/local/cuda directory. I have already build the SDk samples.

On running make command to build the Rodinia benchmark suite I was getting the following errors

```
~/Downloads/rodinia_2.4$ make
cd cuda/cfd;            make;   cp euler3d euler3d_double pre_euler3d pre_euler3d_double /home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/bin/linux/cuda

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/cfd'

nvcc  -O2 -Xptxas -v --gpu-architecture=compute_20 --gpu-code=compute_20 euler3d.cu -o euler3d -I/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/common/inc  -L/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/lib 

euler3d.cu:5: fatal error: helper_cuda.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [euler3d] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/cfd'
cp: cannot stat `euler3d': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `euler3d_double': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `pre_euler3d': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `pre_euler3d_double': No such file or directory
make: *** [CUDA] Error 1
```

But looking into the cfd directory

```
 ncclab@slave13:~/Downloads/rodinia_2.4$ cd cuda/cfd/ls
  **euler3d.cu  euler3d_double.cu  Makefile  Makefile_nvidia  pre_euler3d.cu  pre_euler3d_double.cu**  README  run
```

This is also the case with some other benchmark

```
cd cuda/srad/srad_v2;       make;   cp srad /home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/bin/linux/cuda/srad_v2
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/srad/srad_v2'
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc srad.cu -o srad -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 
srad.cu:6: fatal error: srad.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [release] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ncclab/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/srad/srad_v2'
cp: cannot stat `srad': No such file or directory
make: *** [CUDA] Error 1

ncclab@slave13:~/Downloads/rodinia_2.4/cuda/srad/srad_v2$ ls
Makefile  Makefile_nvidia  README  run  srad.cu  srad.h  srad_kernel.cu
```

It clearly states the files are present in the directory. I can't understand why this error is occurring. Searching here and on google can't help me to find the cause. Can someone please help me.

What is the file helper_cuda.h contains. I cannot find it. Is it something that comes with gpu computing sdk samples. If so I was not having them. Is there any problem in its installation

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the place `-I/if10/kw5na/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK4/C/common/inc` where you should find helper_cuda.h but looks like its not your system path so you should find the file in `YOUR/CUDA_SDK_PATH/samples/common/inc`

Comment: What does CUDA_SDK_PATH mean? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Thats the place where you installed the `CUDA`. On a unix like systems, if you have not specified some folder by default it will be usually `/usr/local/cuda/`

Comment: OK, the CUDA_INSTALL_PATH... but I don't any samples sub-directory in the /usr/local/cuda where I have installed the CUDA

Comment: Either you can remove the inclusion of `helper_cuda.h` or you can download the new sdk and just extract the samples folder.

Comment: @SagarMasuti I have extracted the samples folder by downloading the cuda_5.5. Now where should I move the helper_cuda.h file to overcome this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to the [latest version of CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda) (currently 5.5). You'll find the helper_*.h files in the $CUDA_PATH/samples/common/inc directory.

There version of CUDA that you have installed (CUDA 4.0) is quite old now, and the examples provided with 4.0 used a different set of helper functions in a library called cutil.

Comment: Actually I was working on a simulator which is developed upto CUDA 4.0 version only. So I can't update to version 5.5. So, is there any other way to extract the files from it without actually installing it

Comment: You should be able to install the 5.5 toolkit alongside the older toolkit and just copy the files out.

Comment: I have extracted the samples folder by downloading the cuda_5.5. Now where should I move the helper_cuda.h file to overcome this error

Comment: You need to put it somewhere on your include path, or in the same directory as the source file. nvcc behaves the same as any other C/C++ compiler in this respect.